# How to give names for array elements while send as json data in rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-autocomplete

I have an array like this,

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "employee": [
        ["a",1],
        ["b",2],
        ["c",3],
        ["d", 4] ]
}
```

I use below given code to send the data to the view as the response of an ajax request.

```
  @names= Employee.all.pluck(:name, :id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => { :status => :ok, :employee => @names }.to_json }
    end
```

But I need to give name to the array elements like

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "employee": [
        ["label":"a","value":1],
        ["label":"b","value":2],
        ["label":"c","value":3],
        ["label":"d","value":4] ]
}
```

How I can do that.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need employee to be an array of hashes like below

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "employee": [
    {label: "a", value: 1},
    {label: "b", value: 2},
    {label: "c", value: 3},
    {label: "d", value: 4} ]
}
```

Try the following in your controller:

```
employee = []
@names.each do |name|
  employee << {label: name.name, value: name.id}
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => { :status => :ok, employee }.to_json }
end
```